# Changing page "theme" along with div content

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html, jquery-animate

I'm relatively new to jQuery, and I'm currently having trouble with transitions and AJAX content.

There are basically 4 pages, each with their own "theme" (a unique background image with a tinted overlay DIV).

I've posted the code below. It ***looks*** right to me, in theory. but of course it is not working.

The comments in the code explain the process that I would like to see happen.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {  

      // begin 'photography' theme transition

    $('a.photography').click(function() {  

       // 1. these next two lines hide the content containers and their data 
    $('#contentCanvas_A').fadeOut().hide();  
     $('#contentCanvas_B').fadeOut().hide();

     // 2. animate/fade the tint color for the #contentCanvas overlay
     $('#Window').animate({ backgroundColor: "rgba('67,32,12,0.8')}, "slow"});


     // 3. seamless fade swap of the <body> background image possible? 
     $('body').css('background-image','url(bgimage-photography.jpg)').fadeIn("slow");


      // 4. Finally, fade in new content from external HTML file
     $('#contentCanvas_A').stop().load("photography.html").delay(800).fadeIn("slow");


     });
```

... and this is how the HTML link would look:

```
<a class="photography" href="" title="online photo gallery">Photography</a>
```

Is this the proper/efficient way of doing it? Trying it using variables and the "#" symbol doesn't seem  to work.

Some notes:

I have attempted to create a separate DIV that has the background image, but I could not get it to fill the entire screen -- it only showed the first 5 pixels or so at the top. Therefore, as shown in the code, I'm trying to change the background image for the actual *body* element instead.

The "photography.html" file (and others similar) contains just the DIVs for its own content layout, nothing else.

I would greatly appreciate guidance with this. Thanks all!

Comment: You need to explain what exactly isn't working. And be sure to use absolute paths when changing background images in JS.

Comment: When I click on the link, it simply reloads the current page with no changes (no fade, no color change, nothing) instead of running the jquery function as expected. The script itself runs fine; I checked the error console, and my jQuery is syntactically correct.

Changed URIs to absolute paths, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action from occurring when you click the `<a>`. Just modify the first line of code to read:

`$('a.photography').click(function(e) {`

Note the `e` inside `function(e)`.

Then, within that function, put `e.preventDefault();`. This can go anywhere inside the click handler function.

**Edit --** In response to the comment on my answer:
I'm not 100% sure why you're getting this problem, but I do see one place where your code has an issue:

```
$('#contentCanvas_A').fadeOut().hide();
```

When you do this, the `hide()` method is run immediately after the `fadeOut()` method is called, as opposed to *waiting* for the `fadeOut` method to finish. All of jQuery's animation methods allow you to pass in a "callback" function that will be executed once the animation method finishes. For example:

```
$('#contentCanvas_A').fadeOut(250, function(){
    alert('fadeOut finished!');
});
```

If you do this, you'll see the element fade out and once it is totally gone, you'll get the alert. As an aside, there is no need to call `hide()` here because `fadeOut()` actually does this for you at the very end.

The main piece of your code that should be put inside this callback function (where the alert is) is the final line:

```
 $('#contentCanvas_A').stop().load("photography.html").delay(800).fadeIn("slow");
```

And once you put it inside that callback function, you may find that you no longer need the `delay()` method call because the whole line will already wait for the initial `fadeOut` to finish before getting executed.

Anyway, I'm not sure if this gives you enough info to fully solve your problem. If not, it would be much easier at this point if you'd put your code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that I can play around with it.

Comment: Almost perfect! Thanks for that.  The only issue I'm facing now is that I have to click twice to get the whole function to run its course. When I click the first time, the content disappears, but then I have to click a second time to get the background image to change and the new content to appear. I'm thinking it has to do with the order of my animations, but I'm not sure where to start.   The background overlay color doesn't change, but I'm guessing that's due to an error on my part in implementing the color plugin.

Comment: Another note to add, is don't forget your "callbacks" for things like "fadeout" and "animate".  Example, If u want those first two things to get a better appearance of fading one after another, instead of listing after each other try `$('#contentCanvas_A').fadeOut(function(event){ $('#contentCanvas_B').fadeOut() }); //no need use .hide, fadeout will hide it;`

Comment: one mor thing, if you want them to fade at near the same time, use "setTimeout" as such, `setTimeout(function(){ $('#contentCanvas_A').fadeOut(); }, 1);//1 milisecond wait to catch other one` `$('#contentCanvas_B').fadeOut();//no timeout wait to ride with first`

Comment: Many thanks, both of you! This cleared everything right up. Only things that don't work is the fading of the background image and changing of the tint colour, but I think I can handle that from here; it's something that can be lived without.